# Junit how to get invoking classname in parent @BeforeClass method?

Tags: junit, junit4

I have implemented a generic `TestBase.java` and many test case class extends this base.

`@BeforeClass` method is to prepare some specific data for corresponding test case class.

My question is, is it possible to get the invoking test case classname in TestBase `@BeforeClass` method so that I can use the classname to get correct data prepared?

I don't want to implement the `@BeforeClass` in separate test case class, as the steps are totally the same, the only difference is the data name which can be generated by test case classname.

For example:
My project is to test query function of our product.
Test case classes like GenericQueryTest.java, BooleanQueryTest.java etc.
Each test case class need to index prepared data before run test and cleanup the environment after all tests in the testcase class finish.

I implemented a TestBase.java like following.

public class TestBase {

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
    I want to get invoked test case class name here. if I get the name(eg. classname= "GenericQueryTest ")
    File testDataFile = new File("C:/users/" + classname +".csv";
    then read the "C:/users/GenericQueryTest.csv "to prepare data in env        

}
```

public class GenericQueryTest extends TestBase{

```
 I donot need to implement @BeforeClass

 @Test 
 .....
 @Test
 ...
```

}

Comment: For the record: be careful about using massive amounts of inheritance and "behind the scene" setup for JUnit test cases. The purpose of a failing test is to **quickly** allow you to find the root cause, and fix that. When you first have to study the "hidden" aspects of your test class(es) you are defeating that purpose. Meaning: be really careful about adding complexity to your test cases that requires readers to turn to 2, 3 different places *before* they even understand what the test case is doing.

Comment: It is just a common method to prepareData. What's your advice to avoid implementing the same method in every test case classes?

Comment: What exactly is that method doing? Beyond that, yes, I would probably put that BeforeClass method into each class. You could invoke some other static helper method from there, giving the class name as parameter. But again, you should probably show us a code example instead giving abstract descriptions. We can't suggest different options given the current information.

Comment: Clarified my question above.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to resolve the problem. Just implement customized runner. And you can get Class from the runner.